# Функция strtod() считывает только целую часть вещественного числа

Tags: c++, c

Использую [inih](https://github.com/benhoyt/inih) для парсинга ini файла. Обнаружилось то, что функция INIReader::GetReal(...) возвращает только целую часть вещественного числа.
В комментариях написан пример значений переменных при отладке.

```
double INIReader::GetReal(const string& section, const string& name, double default_value) const
{
    string valstr = Get(section, name, ""); // "1.033"
    const char* value = valstr.c_str(); // "1.033"
    char* end; // ".033"
    double n = std::strtod(value, &end); // 1
    return end > value ? n : default_value;
}
```

[github code function](https://github.com/benhoyt/inih/blob/9d1af9d500dabb27a39560c8c24e2891ba2f1861/cpp/INIReader.cpp#L48)

Компилятор:

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609
```

Comment: Локаль какая стоит? В русской локали целая и вещественная части числа разделяются запятой, а не точкой.

Comment: а в чем вопрос?

Comment: Да, на Windows работало с точкой, а у меня на Ubuntu не работало. Спасибо.

Comment: Ну, на Windows в русской локали так же используется запятая в качестве разделителя. Не в операционке дело, а в локали.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функция `strtod` использует системно-зависимое значение символа разделителя дробной и целой части (decimal separator). И если в системе текущим разделителем является запятая (что характерно для русской локали), функция не сможет правильно распарсить строку, в которой в качестве разделителя использовалась точка. Именно это и происходят в вашем случае.

В качестве решения проблемы можно посоветовать использовать функцию `strtod_l` (`_strtod_l` для Windows) которая принимает третьим параметром локаль с правильным (ожидаемым) разделителем или можно взять готовую обёртку `strtod` ([тут](https://github.com/tknopp/julia/blob/master/src/support/strtod.c) или [тут](https://github.com/OpenImageIO/oiio/blob/a72af0036fdefb9e5650494e6679c1e490df81cc/src/libutil/strutil.cpp#L1163)) которая парсит вещественные числа с предположением, что разделителем является точка, вне зависимости от значения локали.

Comment: Я поменял локаль, но все равно не работает.
'cho 'export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"' >>~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc'

Comment: @Tarakan *Менять* локаль не надо. Надо использовать функцию `strtod_l` с заданной локалью.

Comment: А почему же смена локали не могла? Не хотелось бы менять код библиотеки, да к тому же  вы сказали, что _strtod_l с linux не дружит.

Comment: `setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");` или через `std::locale::global(std::locale("en_US.UTF-8"))`

Comment: Перезагрузил VM и все заработало.

Comment: @Tarakan В Linux/FreeBCD/macOS доступна функция `strtod_l`, а в Windows есть аналогичная по функционалу, но называется `_strtod_l`. Т.е. на всех популярных платформах это можно сделать.